# Let drag and drop merge if the draggeble item is dropped close at the drop zone

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I made a simple game where you have to match the right figures. When you drag a figure near the shadow figure they match. I want to make it so that if you drag the right figure to the right shadow that they merge perfectly. If you open the snippet and try the game you will see that if you drag the square half inside the shasow square the game will accept it (counts it as good).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".selectable").draggable({
    addClasses: false,
    snap: true,
    stack: ".destination",
    scroll: false
  });

  $(".destination").draggable({
    snapMode: "inner"
  });

  $(".destination").draggable("disable");

  $(".destination").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var selectedShape = ui.draggable.attr("id");
      var dropZone = $(this).attr("id");
      dropZone = dropZone.replace("inside", "");
      if (selectedShape == dropZone) {
        $("#" + selectedShape).draggable("disable");
        checkShapeStatus();
      } else {
        
        alert("Wrong choice!");
      }
    }
  });
});

function checkShapeStatus() {
  var counter = 0;
  $(".selectable").each(function() {
    var $thisId = $(this);
    var booleanValue = $thisId.draggable('option', 'disabled');
    if (booleanValue) {
      counter = counter + 1;
    } else {

    }

    if (counter == 4) {
      win.play();
    }

  })
}
```

```css
#square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 8%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#triangle-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid green;
  z-index: 3;
}

#pacman {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  border-top: 60px solid yellow;
  border-left: 60px solid yellow;
  border-bottom: 60px solid yellow;
  border-top-left-radius: 60px;
  border-top-right-radius: 60px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 60px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60px;
  z-index: 4;
}

#squareinside {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}

#circleinside {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#triangle-upinside {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid gray;
}

#pacmaninside {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  border-top: 60px solid gray;
  border-left: 60px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 60px solid gray;
  border-top-left-radius: 60px;
  border-top-right-radius: 60px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 60px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60px;
}

body {
  background-color: bisque;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#centerText {
  font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
  font-size: xx-large;
  style="width:100%;
 height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.grid-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 150px 150px;
}

.grid-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 150px 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Shape Matching</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock+Salt' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="grid-1">
    <div id="pacmaninside" class="destination"></div>
    <div id="triangle-upinside" class="destination"></div>
    <div id="circleinside" class="destination"></div>
    <div id="squareinside" class="destination"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-2">
    <div id="square" class="selectable"></div>
    <div id="circle" class="selectable"></div>
    <div id="triangle-up" class="selectable"></div>
    <div id="pacman" class="selectable"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I would appreciate if someone can change the code and put it here.

Comment: So you want us to fix the pac-man looking object?

Comment: @Rojo No, if you drag a figure near the good shadow you can't drag it again (so the game counts it as good). But the figure doesn's perfectly match with the shadow.

Comment: It's already doing that; I can't drag it around once it's correct

Comment: @Rojo yes i know but that is not the issue. Do you have discord? I can explain nthe issue in a better way with a screen shot of what i mean.

Comment: Yeah you can add me RohitRojo#4945

Answer (score 0):

You can check the coordinates of dropzone and dropped object:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".selectable").draggable({
    addClasses: false,
    snap: true,
    stack: ".destination",
    scroll: false
  });

  $(".destination").draggable({
    snapMode: "inner"
  });

  $(".destination").draggable("disable");

  $(".destination").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var selectedShape = ui.draggable.attr("id");
      var dropZone = $(this).attr("id");
      dropZone = dropZone.replace("inside", "");
      var destPos = ui.draggable.position(),
          selPos = $(this).position();

      if (selectedShape == dropZone && selPos.left == destPos.left && selPos.top == destPos.top) {
        $("#" + selectedShape).draggable("disable");
        checkShapeStatus();
      } else {
        
        alert("Wrong choice!");
      }
    }
  });
});

function checkShapeStatus() {
  var counter = 0;
  $(".selectable").each(function() {
    var $thisId = $(this);
    var booleanValue = $thisId.draggable('option', 'disabled');
    if (booleanValue) {
      counter = counter + 1;
    } else {

    }

    if (counter == 4) {
      win.play();
    }

  })
}
```

```css
#square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 8%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}

#triangle-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid green;
  z-index: 3;
}

#pacman {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  border-top: 60px solid yellow;
  border-left: 60px solid yellow;
  border-bottom: 60px solid yellow;
  border-top-left-radius: 60px;
  border-top-right-radius: 60px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 60px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60px;
  z-index: 4;
}

#squareinside {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}

#circleinside {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

#triangle-upinside {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid gray;
}

#pacmaninside {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  border-top: 60px solid gray;
  border-left: 60px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 60px solid gray;
  border-top-left-radius: 60px;
  border-top-right-radius: 60px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 60px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60px;
}

body {
  background-color: bisque;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#centerText {
  font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
  font-size: xx-large;
  style="width:100%;
 height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.grid-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 150px 150px;
}

.grid-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 150px 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Shape Matching</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock+Salt' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="grid-1">
    <div id="pacmaninside" class="destination"></div>
    <div id="triangle-upinside" class="destination"></div>
    <div id="circleinside" class="destination"></div>
    <div id="squareinside" class="destination"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-2">
    <div id="square" class="selectable"></div>
    <div id="circle" class="selectable"></div>
    <div id="triangle-up" class="selectable"></div>
    <div id="pacman" class="selectable"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @henri-bunt Kan je me op discord helpen met nog een spel? (skip deze stackoverflow haha)